# Describe table with all its columns names, their data types, constraints and dependent table (in case of foreign key) in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to display a table with all its columns name along with data types, constraints and the referred table (in case of foreign key) etc in oracle? I need to write a piece of code which can make this kind of query and then based on result can create the table programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

[DBMS_METADATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026) package is used for such a purpose. For example:

```
SQL> set long 10000
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, user)
  2  from user_objects;

<output is quite long, so I'm not going to post it here>
```

Comment: It always says table not found for some reason.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add copy/paste of your SQL*Plus session so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded.